# How create directory structure with permissions from web?

Tags: active-directory, scripting, network-share, web

I have a directory structure in a shared folder with specific folder permissions for making projects in a Active Directory Domain like \server\shared\Projects\Project1, \server\shared\Projects\Project2, \server\shared\Projects\Project3...  There is no user that have full permissions on the projects folder and I have created a script to set the permissions, but only a user with full permissions like the AD domain can execute the script (a .ps1 or a .vbs) and set them

I was thinking if a web server with AD authentication can do the work. A user with privileges logs into the web with the credentials, give a name for the project and push a button, in the server side a script is running that create the folder wiht right permissions and returns the output to the web.

How can I start? Is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

I am thinking about using Jenkins in Windows Server with Powershell Script with de AD plugin, with this scenario I think a user can log in to the Jenkins web interface and run a script that creates the folder, I will search the option and I will post it here.